# How to create a colorway picker/color wheel for web store theme background and model color shape using ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, sass, react-redux

[image]I'm working on a project using ReactJS and I need to implement a colour picker that allows the user to select a colour for the web background and modal colour shape. I've done some research but I couldn't find a clear solution that fits my needs.

**the requirement is** The colourway picker wheel associated with the model is displayed as a 24-trapezoidal button wheel representing available colourways.
Only a portion of the wheel is visible on the screen, with the rest off-screen. As not all models will have the same number of colourways,
the wheel may have empty spaces. On the reference image, some colourways have locker icons with a white border to indicate unavailability for customers of their current rank.

Could you please guide me on how to implement a colour picker for both the web background and modal colour shape using ReactJS? Are there any libraries or packages that I can use?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to build and make its functionality but I cannot able to build the shape as the requirement defined and when I applied the rotation on the wheel it stuck and moved continuously
as I've attached the image as well

[image]